# Which scope is needed to get the permission to access the chat and send message from linkedin api token

Tags: postman, linkedin-api, access-token

I created a Linkedin API access token using these scopes
("scope": "r_basicprofile,r_emailaddress,r_organization_admin,r_organization_social,rw_organization_admin,w_member_social,w_organization_social").

But when I hit the message API https://api.linkedin.com/v2/messages using this access token with a request body :
{
"recipients": [
"urn:li:person:123ABC",
"urn:li:person:456DEF"
],
"subject": "Group conversation title",
"body": "Hello everyone! This is a message conversation to demo the Message API.",
"messageType": "MEMBER_TO_MEMBER",
"attachments": [
"urn:li:digitalMediaAsset:123ABC"
]
}

I'm getting this response
{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: POST /messages",
"status": 403
}

please help me with this API , how can I send a message using it?